# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2) in initialize with inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, rspec

Okay,

this is driving me nuts, since I don't understand the error in this case.
I have the following class defined:

```
module Admins
  class BasePresenter < ::BasePresenter
    def render_customer(id:)
      return I18n.t('admin.admin') if id.nil?
      ::Customer.where(id: id).first.try(:name) || I18n.t('admin.deleted')
    end

    def percent_of(count, total)
      ((count.to_f / total.to_f) * 100.0).to_i
    end
  end
end
```

Which inherits from the `BasePresenter` below:

```
class BasePresenter

  def initialize(object, template)
    @object = object
    @template = template
  end

  def self.presents(name)
    define_method(name) do
      @object
    end
  end

  def underscored_class
    @object.class.name.underscore
  end


  protected


  def h
    @template
  end

  def handle_none(value, html = true)
    if value.present?
      if block_given?
        yield
      else
        value
      end
    else
      return h.content_tag(:span, '-', class: 'none') if html
      '-'
    end
  end

  def current_customer
    @current_customer ||= h.current_customer
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= h.current_user
  end

end
```

However when I try to run my specs, I receive the following error from RSpec:

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)
>   ./app/presenters/base_presenter.rb:3:in `initialize'
>   ./spec/presenters/admins/base_presenter_spec.rb:24:in`block (3
>   levels) in '

The class is no different from other presents, where the the inheritance works in the exact same way and those tests are passing.
Just the test for this class is failing with this error, and only when testing the method `percent_of`.

What am I failing to see?

**EDIT**

This is my RSpec test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ::Admins::BasePresenter do
  describe '#render_customer' do

    let(:customer) { Customer.first }
    subject { ::Admins::BasePresenter.new(Object.new, ApplicationController.new.view_context) }

    it 'returns the I18n translations for (admin) when no customer is set.' do
      expect(subject.render_customer(id: nil)).to eql(I18n.t('admin.admin'))
    end

    it 'returns the proper name when a valid ID is given' do
      expect(subject.render_customer(id: customer.id)).to eql(customer.name)
    end

    it 'returns the I18n translations for (deleted) when an invalid ID is given' do
      expect(subject.render_customer(id: -1)).to eql(I18n.t('admin.deleted'))
    end
  end

  describe '#percent_of' do
    it 'calculates the percentage correctly' do
      expect(subject.percent_of(0, 1)).to eql(0)
      expect(subject.percent_of(1, 1)).to eql(100)
      expect(subject.percent_of(1, 2)).to eql(50)
      expect(subject.percent_of(1, 3)).to eql(33)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh,

I'm an idiot....
The problem was that my `subject` was defined inside a Describe block for specific tests and the second one did not have any.
Which means our hooks try to create an instance of the class in the outer describe block...

This was the fix:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ::Admins::BasePresenter do
  let(:customer) { Customer.first }
  subject { ::Admins::BasePresenter.new(Object.new, ApplicationController.new.view_context) }

  describe '#render_customer' do
    it 'returns the I18n translations for (admin) when no customer is set.' do
      expect(subject.render_customer(id: nil)).to eql(I18n.t('admin.admin'))
    end

    it 'returns the proper name when a valid ID is given' do
      expect(subject.render_customer(id: customer.id)).to eql(customer.name)
    end

    it 'returns the I18n translations for (deleted) when an invalid ID is given' do
      expect(subject.render_customer(id: -1)).to eql(I18n.t('admin.deleted'))
    end
  end

  describe '#percent_of' do
    it 'calculates the percentage correctly' do
      expect(subject.percent_of(0, 1)).to eql(0)
      expect(subject.percent_of(1, 1)).to eql(100)
      expect(subject.percent_of(1, 2)).to eql(50)
      expect(subject.percent_of(1, 3)).to eql(33)
    end
  end
end
```